# Transform a table within SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table test looks like

```
Month|CA     |CATTC | CA     |CATTC
------------------------------------
1    |100    |20    | 250    |120  
5    |100    |30    | 202    |140  
12   |130    |260   | 255    |130
```

My goal is to get a table `test 2` like

```
Month|CA     |CATTC    
--------------------
1    |100    |20       
5    |100    |30        
12   |130    |260        
1    |250    |120   
5    |202    |140   
12   |255    |130
```

Is it possible within SQL Server?

Comment: You can't have the same column name twice. How are we supposed to chose one of the two CA's?

Comment: You can create view as per your table

Comment: I dont think you have a table like you showed us..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this,

```
CREATE TABLE #TEMP
(
    [Month] INT,
    CA INT,
    CASTTC INT,
    CA1 INT,
    CATTC1 INT
)


INSERT INTO #TEMP VALUES
(1    ,100    ,20    , 250    ,120),  
(5    ,100    ,30    , 202    ,140),  
(12   ,130    ,260   , 255    ,130) 

SELECT [Month],CrossApplied.CA,CrossApplied.CASTTC FROM #TEMP
CROSS APPLY (VALUES (CA,CASTTC),(CA1,CATTC1)) CrossApplied(CA,CASTTC)
```

(OR)

```
SELECT [Month],
       CrossApplied.CA,
       CrossApplied.CASTTC
FROM   #TEMP
       CROSS APPLY (SELECT CA,
                           CASTTC
                    UNION ALL
                    SELECT CA1,
                           CATTC1) CrossApplied(CA, CASTTC)
```

Comment: why use both `CROSS APPLY` and `UNION ALL` in the same query?

Answer (score 2):

Change columns names, then do a `UNION ALL`:

```
select Month, CA1 as CA, CATTC1  as CATTC from tablename
UNION ALL
select Month, CA2, CATTC2 from tablename
```

Answer (score 0):

CATTC column is dublicate,  change to CATTC_
and use "union all"

```
CREATE TABLE #dt
(
    [Month] INT,
    CA INT,
    CATTC INT,
    CA1 INT,
    CATTC_ INT
)

INSERT INTO #dt VALUES
(1    ,100    ,20    , 250    ,120),  
(5    ,100    ,30    , 202    ,140),  
(12   ,130    ,260   , 255    ,130) 

select [Month], CA, CATTC  from #dt
union all 
select [Month], CA, CATTC_ from #dt
```